# AJAX JQUERY Php form not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

issues are still there...pls help

I am unable to load external file while using AJAX jquery. I want to use Jquery ajax to pop up form then validate, enter data in mysql. but starting from a simple ajax function. kindly let me know where i am going wrong

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="test_style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){
var str = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax(
{
type: "POST",
url:"contact.php",
data: str,
success:function(result)
{
$("#div1").html(result);
}
});
});
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="contact_form">
<form id="ajax-contact-form" name="contact" action=""> 
<fieldset>
<label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
<label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label>

<INPUT class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">
</fieldset>
</form>
</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

and contact.php file is

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Since you are posting your form through ajax, you must prevent the default form submit by returning a false inside the submit method. Below is the correct version:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){
   var str = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:"contact.php",
     data: str,
     success:function(result) {
        $("#div1").html(result);
     }
  });
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `return false;` to prevent the form from submitting and refreshing the page and check if your `$("#div1")` is missing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){
         var str = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax(
         {
             type: "POST",
             url:"contact.php",
             data: str,
             success:function(result)
             {
                  $("#div1").html(result);
             }
          });
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: please mention missing `div1`

Comment: @legendinmaking: i think the div should be somewhere else that the OP does not show in his code. Anyway, updated the code to remind him in case he forgot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are missing the div1

please use

```
<div id="div1"><div>
```

Comment: Sorry you are using ajax submit

**$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){** you are unable to show the result. You need to use **return false;**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more simple form of post request as follows:

```
$.post("url",{var1: value1, var2: value2},function(data,status){
 if(status=='success')
   alert(data);
});
```

the second argument you can pass as many using this post request. The first argument url, if ofcourse `relative to the document in which this js is loaded` or you can give the exact url on the server.

According to your php file, data=='Hello'.

Similar is the procedure for any `GET` request also.